# Get N Keys From Redis In Production

Tags: redis, production

I am trying to retrieve N keys from Redis in production. When I tried to get `keys *` from Redis Server, it returns all of the keys after a long response time (My Redis server contains minimum ~10M rows at a moment). Therefore after I searched for a solution, I found `HSCAN` command to get N number of keys. However in the Redis documentation it says:

> The SCAN algorithm is guaranteed to terminate only if the size of the iterated collection remains bounded to a given maximum size, otherwise iterating a collection that always grows may result into SCAN to never terminate a full iteration.
>   This is easy to see intuitively: if the collection grows there is more and more work to do in order to visit all the possible elements, and the ability to terminate the iteration depends on the number of calls to SCAN and its COUNT option value compared with the rate at which the collection grows.

I thought I cannot use this solution because my Redis server always writes key-value pairs into a hash during the day. The hash always grows and there might be problems in terminating `HSCAN` command.

Comment: `HSCAN` is the polite equivalent of `HKEYS` - both return the fields inside a Hash data structure (that's the value of a Redis key). The real question is why are you trying to get all your fields (or keys)? A full scan is usually not something you want to do.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Actually I'm not trying to get all of my keys. What I'm trying to do is I want to get N number of keys and their values so that I can manipulate and use them in my code chunk by chunk. However the number of fields are so big, I'm forcing my Redis Server. On the other hand, that retrieving that huge number keys locks my server in the name of response time.

Comment: Sometimes a Lua script can help in such cases. What kind of processing and how big is the data (the number of fields or keys)?

Comment: @ItamarHaber the number is not stable but just like I said in the question, it contains min ~10M fields at a moment. About the process, it is not important what kind of process that I make I think. Because retrieving keys from the Redis server makes the bottleneck in my structure

Comment: You could copy the Hash key and then SCAN it - that would give you a polite way to scan the N keys (as changes will continue on the original key). OTOH, you'll be using double the RAM while the copy exists. BTW, the fastest way to copy a key is to use DUMP/RESTORE - see: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/d30b3c40a72a07f23c70